# Show up a button with an interval in rpanel

Tags: r

```
stopme <- function(panel) panel$i<=20
callme <- function(panel) {
for(i in 1:20){
rp.button(panel,  "press me", name="b1")
rp.widget.dispose(panel, "b1" )

panel$i = panel$i+1
panel
}
} 
panel <- rp.control(i=1)
rp.timer(panel, 500, callme, stopme)
Error in if (where(panel)) timer <- handshake(tcl, "after", microseconds,  
argument is of length zero
```

I want to show that the button will show up in an interval. But there is an error that I can't fix it. Could anyone help me?